# What to name data structure that converts to friendly names?

Tags: javascript, naming

I've just created a data structure to convert from back-end database field names to friendly names that are displayed to the user.

```
let converter = {
    "t": "Time (s)",
    "v": "Velocity (m/s)",
    "acc": "Acceleration (m/s^2",
}
```

where I can call it like so:

```
let dataReceived = {t: [1, 2, 3], v: [4, 5, 6], acc: [1, 1, 1]};
console.log("Value for " + converter['t'] + " is " + dataReceived.t);
```

Is there a common name for this pattern? Like friendly name-ifier?

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [associative array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), dictionary or a map. In your case the term dictionary would be fitting, and I would choose the associating/translating/transforming/mapping verb to describe the action.

Since you already use ES6, you can use an actual [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const converter = new Map([["t", "Time (s)"], ["v", "Velocity (m/s)"], ["acc",  "Acceleration (m/s^2)"]]);

const dataReceived = {t: [1, 2, 3], v: [4, 5, 6], acc: [1, 1, 1]};
console.log("Value for " + converter.get('t') + " is " + dataReceived.t);
```

Comment: sure. the data structure is called a dictionary or a map. but I'm talking more about the action of converting from a "machine" name to a "friendly" name.

Comment: "mapping" would be the verb I guess? That's more generic than what i'm looking for

Comment: To give you a better idea, i have a folder with a *ton* of these. And a lot of code that will be using these. Just calling them maps will be confusing (especially since we use cartographic maps elsewhere in the application)

Comment: Mapping/binding values. Creating a dictionary, or translating values...

Comment: Call them dictionaries, since you are using them for translations or transformation of values.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus If the intention is to make the values more readable for humans, but without otherwise changing their meanings, maybe *prettification* would describe that process?

Comment: @Crice that's pretty good. That's the type of word i'm looking for.